# to parse xml file in python

Tags: regex, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I want to parse a xml file and make a dictionary based on it. And i need to use regular expressions to compute it.

```
<abc:ROW time_stamp="123">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <field1>field_value<field1>
    <field2>field_value</field2>
</abc:ROW>
<abc:ROW time_stamp="456">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <field1>field_value<field1>
    <field2>field_value</field2>
</abc:ROW>
```

The expected result is the List of dictionary with the key value pair such as

```
abcd = [{
  "field1" = field_value,
  "field2" = field_value
}, {
  "field1" = field_value,
  "field2" = field_value
}]
```

Someone please help.

Comment: it's better to use a xml parser

Comment: do you recommend ETree? and i want to know how it can be done by regex

Comment: Anyone which you find suitable for you use cases. If you still want regex solution. than adding in question what you have tried till now will get you more answers.

Comment: i am new to python, i am not sure which combination of regex functions i  have to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XML should better be parsed using a lib like [Beautiful Soup](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) instead of regex. I can give you a perfect regex solution to this but I will surely attract downvotes for it :)

I would suggest you to go through the link and get familiar with it so you don't choose regex whenever you need to parse HTML/XML/Json.

Also, your XML is a little malformed, as `/` is missing in some of your field tags which I have fixed.

You would need somewhat this kind of python code to parse the XML and aggregate the data as a list of dictionaries.

```
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = '''<abc:ROW time_stamp="123">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <field1>field_value11</field1>
    <field2>field_value12</field2>
</abc:ROW>
<abc:ROW time_stamp="456">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <field1>field_value21</field1>
    <field2>field_value22</field2>
</abc:ROW>'''


abcd = []
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

for abcTag in soup.find_all('abc:row'):
 dict = {}
 dict['field1'] = abcTag.field1.get_text()
 dict['field2'] = abcTag.field2.get_text()
 abcd.append(dict)

print(abcd)
```

Which prints,

```
[{'field1': 'field_value11', 'field2': 'field_value12'}, {'field1': 'field_value21', 'field2': 'field_value22'}]
```

Hope this helps and let me know for any queries.

**Edit: Solution using pure regex as per OP's special request**

There are two (and can be multiple) `<abc:ROW` tags so you can use this regex

```
(?s)<abc.*?</abc:ROW>
```

to match the text in tags, and then further iterate the matched text using for loop and further apply this regex,

```
<field1>(.*?)</field1>\s*<field2>(.*?)</field2>
```

to capture `field1` tag's value and `field2` tag's value and store them in dictionary, and add the dictionary to the `abcd` list.

Here is the python code to give you the idea,

```
import re

data = '''<abc:ROW time_stamp="123">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <field1>field_value11</field1>
    <field2>field_value12</field2>
</abc:ROW>
<abc:ROW time_stamp="456">
    <name>abcd</name>
    <field1>field_value21</field1>
    <field2>field_value22</field2>
</abc:ROW>'''


abcd = []

for abcTag in re.findall(r'(?s)<abc.*?</abc:ROW>',data):
 dict = {}
 match = re.search(r'<field1>(.*?)</field1>\s*<field2>(.*?)</field2>', abcTag)
 dict['field1'] = match.group(1)
 dict['field2'] = match.group(2)
 abcd.append(dict)

print(abcd)
```

Which prints following output as you expected,

```
[{'field1': 'field_value11', 'field2': 'field_value12'}, {'field1': 'field_value21', 'field2': 'field_value22'}]
```

Comment: it would be of great help if you can tell me how regex can be applied here. Apparently due to some reasons , i cant use Beautiful Soup library.

Comment: @NewB: Ok I am updating my answer to provide you a pure regex solution.

Comment: @NewB: Updated my answer with pyre regex solution. Let me know if you have any queries.